# Where does Bundler install gems pulled from Github?

Tags: macos, ruby-on-rails-4, github, rvm, bundler

I want to put a debugger in a file for testing, but can't find where Bundler installs gems pulled from Github on my local machine.

I've looked at this thread http://bundler.io/v1.5/git.html which shows how to setup a local file repo to pull from, but I would rather avoid this as my situation is a one off debugging scenario.

Answer (score 2):

I use rbenv for my ruby and gem management. When I pull in a gem from a git repo, it places the files for the gem here:

`/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/gem-name-SHA/`

Comment: Ah I see, I use rvm and it seem to install in a different place than local gems.

Comment: I think you can just run `rvm gemdir` to find what your local directory is for gems (it's been quite a while since I used RVM :))

Comment: That's the command, but that only shows where locally installed gems are stored.

Comment: Sorry, Clay ... isn't that what you were looking for? Where the local gems are stored so you could throw in a breakpoint, etc.? Apologies if I misunderstood your request

Comment: Yes, I didn't state that well. For gems in my Gemfile that are getting pulled from Github( a remote source) I am looking for where they are installed on my local machine. They don't get installed in the same place as the rest of the gems that are installed without specifying a source. Normally you can run gem which [GEM] and it tells you where it's stored, but not when pulled from remote server.

Comment: Oh! Gotcha! My bad ... I did not realize that RVM installed them elsewhere (RBENV is really good about just throwing them all in the same "folder" if you will). Quick question: what IDE/Text editor do you use? FWIW, RubyMine, which I know lots of devs don't want, has a great feature where you can get right to a gem (where it's locally installed) and edit/mess it up, etc.

Comment: Props to Rbenv and RubyMine, I use spacemacs:)

Answer (score 2):

On my machine bundler installed the gem in:

```
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bundler/gems/gem-from-github
```

Answer (score 0):

`gem which [GEM]` doesn't work on its own, but `bundle exec gem which [GEM]` does.